# Why are exceptions always accepted as a return type (when thrown)?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, compilation

> **Why are exceptions always accepted as a return type (thrown)?**

**Valid** example 1:

```
  public string foo()
    {
     return "Hello World!";
    }
```

**Invalid** example (obviously):

```
public string foo()
{
 return 8080;
}
```

**Valid** example 2:

```
public string foo()
{
 throw new NotImplementedException("Hello Stackoveflow!");
}
```

I can see that my "**Invalid Example**" is 'throwing' and not 'returning' the Exception, however, my method does never return the type defined by the method. How come my compiler allows this to compile?

Comment: Because it can tell that the method will never complete normally.  So the return value can never be used.  No point in complaining about that.

Comment: The compiler just has to verify that all possible code paths never reach the last closing brace. The method in question never does. Job well done.

Comment: Because it is thrown on the same thread.

Comment: @Carl Threads have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Task returns exception to caller thread while shuting down the one that cought the exception. There is nowhere to return the exception message here so it simply crashes.

Comment: @Carl How is this a task? this code get executed on the main thread. Tasks run on a separate thread

Comment: @NickProzee That is exactly what I am saying. This is running on main thread and it will crash it if not handled as it is in this case, thus it can be accepted as a return type. If it were on different thread it would crash it and move to main thread if it wont be handled in main thread it would crash whole system. That was my of explaining.

Comment: Guess I read it too quickly ;). So what you are saying is that throwing an exception before the closing bracket, Is compiled as a handled error in code. that Is why the compiler compiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exceptions are not return types, exceptions indicate an error in the method and that it cannot continue.

Your valid example 2 does not return anything, the compiler knows that it will always throw an exception, so it does not need to worry about returning.

If you had:

```
public string foo(int something)
{
  if(something > 10){
    throw new NotImplementedException("Hello Stackoveflow!");
  }
}
```

it would complain, because you are not returning a value all the time.

Also, from your example, if you had: `string val = something()` in your code, val would never get set, because an exception is not a return value.

However, it is valid code, your function can either return a value based on its signature or throw an exception.  If anything, you might expect a warning by the compiler.  I'm not sure about C#, but in java if you have code that is determined to be unreachable you will get warnings, such as:

```
public string foo(int something)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException("Hello Stackoveflow!");
  return "OK";
}
```

This code would give you a warning, because it is impossible for this method to reach the return statement (but it is still valid code, at least if it were Java).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What is kind of weird in my opinion... the compiler allows me to always make an error occur (force exception like example 2), but not compile a different result type because this results in an error?

Comment: @NickProzee because it is not compile time error. Since syntax is correct. Maybe microsoft will include it in latter releases if there is any purpose for it.

Comment: @mikeb, I don't think there will be any purpose for it. I thought this was an intriguing question. Good job on the explanation.

Comment: @NickProzee There are situations in which you'd always want an exception to be thrown. It is valid code, and forcing you to have a return statement of some sort after an exception would be redundant. In your example 2, you are obviously trying to return something of a different type than what was declared, which the compiler can see is just plain *wrong*. Sort of apples and oranges.

Comment: @NickProzee - it is valid code, your function can either return a value based on its signature or throw an exception.  If anything, you might expect a warning from the compiler, but it should not be a compile error.

Answer (score -1):

You can read about exceptions here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Exceptions give you information about ocurred error. You can easly handle and throw them.

Comment: this is more compiler related. sorry but this is bad advice, take a look at @mikeb. it is an informative answer providing clear information.